# Proper way to pass a webdriver to another class

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm

I want to pass my WebDriver to another class instead of passing it to the individual methods within that class. That would mean passing it to the constructor of the class when I create an instance of it. Here is my code, and my issue further below -

```
public class StepDefinitions{

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    CustomWaits waits;

    @Before("@setup") 
    public void setUp() {
        driver = utilities.DriverFactory.createDriver(browserType);
        System.out.println("# StepDefinitions.setUp(), driver = " + driver);
        waits = new CustomWaits(driver);
    }
}


public class CustomWaits {
    WebDriver driver;

    public CustomWaits(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
public boolean explicitWaitMethod(String id) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
            status = element.isDisplayed();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
    }
```

The error I am getting in is `NullPointerException` when a method of that class is called within an @Given, @When, etc. This is a scope issue I cannot resolve.

Feature File:

```
@test
Feature: Test 

  @setup
  Scenario: Navigate to Webpage and Assert Page Title
    Given I am on the "google" Website
    Then page title is "google"
```

Here is the step definition:

```
@Given("^element with id \"([^\"]*)\" is displayed$")
public void element_is_displayed(String link) throws Throwable {
  if (waits.explicitWaitMethod(link)) { 
    // This is where waits becomes null when I put a breakpoint

    driver.findElement(By.id(link)).isDisplayed();
  } else {
    System.out.println("Timed out waiting for element to display");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, I add a print in `setUp()`, please run and tell me what print out.   I suspect the `setUp()` function is not invoked during running.

Comment: When I use page object model, this method works. But this way is causing me issue. I call the method from a @Given, do you think that has something to do with it? Using a break point, waits is null within the Given method

Comment: It's very simple thing, just run my updated code and tell me the output in console, then I can know the `setup()` function in invoked or not.   The string `# StepDefinitions.setUp(), driver = xxx`  is expected to be in console output

Comment: And show your cucumber feature file, did you add tag `@setup` in feature file?

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: To share the webdriver between steps, it is recommended to use Dependency Injection (DI). Cucumber works with several DI frameworks, including Spring, Guice or PicoContainer. If you're not using a DI framework yet, PicoCointainer is a lightweight framework to use.

Comment: @yong here is the printout - # StepDefinitions.setUp(), driver = ChromeDriver: chrome on MAC (0676fd23eef71b56d7dfcfb91ccf32bf)

Comment: @yong feature file added above

Comment: Show the file which includes the function `element_is_displayed()`, I need to how you declare and init the varaible `waits` which used in `element_is_displayed`

Comment: @yong I figured it out sort of. It seems Before ("setup") is destroying the objects after each scenario; I created another Before("tag") and put the objects there and labeled the scenarios with the tag where I use the objects and it worked. But why does the driver not get destroyed after using the "setup" tag only once in the feature file?(I don't have to put the tag "setup" on each scenario for the driver to always work...

Comment: @yong - method included

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
public class StepDefinitions{

    public StepDefinitions() {
        driver = utilities.DriverFactory.createDriver(browserType);
        System.out.println("# StepDefinitions.setUp(), driver = " + driver);
        waits = new CustomWaits(driver);
    }

    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static CustomWaits waits;

    @Given("^element with id \"([^\"]*)\" is displayed$")
    public void element_is_displayed(String link) throws Throwable {
       if (waits.explicitWaitMethod(link)) { 
          // This is where waits becomes null when I put a breakpoint

          driver.findElement(By.id(link)).isDisplayed();
       } else {
          System.out.println("Timed out waiting for element to display");
       }
    }

}


public class CustomWaits {
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public CustomWaits(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public boolean explicitWaitMethod(String id) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
            status = element.isDisplayed();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```